# Error in Converting a Map to ConcurrentMap in Java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a `Map<String,Object>` to be converted to a `ConcurrentMap<String,Object>`

```
    Map<String,Object> testMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    testMap.put("test", null); //This null causing issues in conversion
    testMap.put("test2","123");
    testMap.put("test3",234);
    ConcurrentMap<String,Object> concMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(testMap);
```

I get a null pointer exception. If I copy to a new `HashMap<String,Object>`

```
    Map<String,Object> testMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    testMap.put("test", null);
    testMap.put("test2","123");
    testMap.put("test3",234);
    Map<String,Object> concMap = new HashMap<>(testMap);
```

I don't get any errors. Is there a safe way to a `Map<String,Object>` to a `ConcurrentMap<String,Object>` without the `NullPointerException`

Comment: The question was if there is a safe way to convert a Map to a ConcurrentMap so I don't see why this was closed a a duplicate

Comment: You can make use of `Optional.empty()` for null values if you want to convert to ConcurrentMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the source code of ConcurrentHashMap you will see, it doesn't allow null key or value -

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap#putVal

/** Implementation for put and putIfAbsent */
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
    if (key == null || value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's in the [documentation for `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.

As for other ConcurrentMaps, [the only other implementation `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, does not allow null either](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

Comment: Please do not edit other answers to include your answer in theirs, thanks.

Comment: @Zabuza Accidentally edited yours, undid it already in case you haven't noticed. There wasn't really a good reason to "include my answer in yours" since your answer was already the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not about converting a `HashMap` into `ConcurrentHashMap`. It is more about  `ConcurrentHashMap` being null-safe, it does not allow `null` values. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Like `Hashtable` but unlike `HashMap`, this class **does not allow** `null` to be used as a key or value.